# How to convert an integer according to international number system in java (Number Formatting)

Tags: java, string, integer, number-formatting

I want to convert a given number according to international number system. // For example:

```
345678 -> 345,678
12 -> 12 
123 -> 123
4590 -> 4,590
```

Here is the code snippet and [IdeOne link](http://ideone.com/ePiYPJ)

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int number = 345678;
    String s = Integer.toString(number);
    s = putCommas(s);
}

private String putCommas(String s) {
    // How to put commas in string after every 3rd character from right ?
}
```

Here is my approach with which I am not comfortable.

1. Start traversing string from right
2. If the (length - currentIndex -1) % 3 == 0 insert comma in the string

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) with [`Locale#US`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US):

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(number);
```

Or [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
String newNumber = formatter.format(number);
```

Comment: Thanks..I didn't know about Formatter class. Decimal example helped a lot..Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

Use the `NumberFormat` class

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getInstance(java.util.Locale)

You can pass it in a Locale and then `format` the number as required

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format(long)

```
System.out.println (NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(1234567L));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply [NumberFormat class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) .

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
//allows to have number seperated by comma
numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);

String formattedNr = numberFormat.format(12345678L);
System.out.println("12345678L number formatted to " + formattedNr);
```

Output:

> 12345678L number formatted to 12,345,678.00